# MySQL C# Text Encoding Problems

Tags: c#, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have an old MySQL database with encoding set to UTF-8. I am using Ado.Net Entity framework to connect to it.

The string that I retrieve from it have strange characters when ë like characters are expected.

For example: "ë" is "Ã«".

I thought I could get this right by converting from UTF8 to UTF16.

```
 return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(                
            Encoding.Convert(
            Encoding.UTF8,
            Encoding.Unicode,
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8)));
    }
```

This however doesn't change a thing.

How could I get the data from this database in proper form?

Comment: The problem is more than likely in the MySql storage.  What does your table look like?

Answer (score 38):

There are two things that you need to do to support UTF-8 in the ADO.NET Entity frame work (or in general using the MySQL .NET Connector):

1. Ensure that the collation of your database of table is a UTF-8 collation (i.e. `utf8_general_ci` or one of its relations)
2. Add `Charset=utf8;` to your connection string.

   ```
   "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=test;Pwd=test;Charset=utf8;"
   ```

I'm not certain, but the encoding may be case sensitive; **I found that `CharSet=UTF8;` did not work for me.**

Comment: i have already add this info to connectionstring, but can not work.

Comment: <add name="ZscqContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=zscq;Charset=utf8;uid=root;password=Ware4u;"/>

Answer (score 3):

Even if the database is set to UTF8 you must do the following things to get Unicode fields to work correctly:

1. Ensure you are using a Unicode field type like *NVARCHAR* or *TEXT CHARSET utf8*
2. Whenever you insert anything into the field you must prefix it with the N character to indicate Unicode data as shown in the examples below
3. Whenever you select based on Unicode data ensure you use the N prefix again

---

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (someField) VALUES (N'Unicode Data')");

MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE someField=N'Unicode Data'");
```

If the database wasn't configured correctly or the data was inserted without using the N prefix it won't be possible to get the correct data out since it will have been downcast into the Latin 1/ASCII character set

Comment: I'm afraid that that downcast issue is the case.
The tables are in UTF8, but the fields are just VARCHAR. 

Is there no way to "upcast" it to utf8 or whatever coding to get the data back?

Comment: Strangely, the Ruby on Rails app that uses the database doesn't seem to have any problems with getting the data correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try set the encoding by "set names utf8" query. You can set this parameter in mysql config too.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said this could be a db issue, but it could also be caused by using an old version of the .net mysql connector.

What I actually wanted to comment on was the utf8 to utf16 conversion. The string you are trying to convert is actually alreay unicode encoded, so your "Ã«" characters actually takes up 4 bytes (or more) and are no longer, at the point of your conversion, a misrepresentation of the "ë" character. That is the reason why your conversion doesn't do anything.
If you want to do a conversion like that I think you would have to encode your utf8 string as a old style 1 byte per character string, using a codepage where the byte values of Ã and « actually represent the utf8 byte sequence of ë and then treat the bytes of this new string as an utf8 string. Fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

thank you The Mouth of a Cow ,
your solution works but still we need converting characters.
i think this is your problem :)
and for converting characters you can use this code

```
 System.Text.Encoding utf_8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

 string s = "unicode";

 //string to utf
 byte[] utf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

 //utf to string
 string s2= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=test;Pwd=test;Charset=utf8;"
```

It worked - PowerShell 7.2, MySQL Connector 8.0.29

Answer (score -1):

Just Remove this Package:

```
Mysql.Data
```

and install following package:

```
MySql.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Edit your answer by adding documentation or link to support your answer inother to make it more acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Use MySql Server Under 8.0.3 Version

Comment: this is just a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35489655)