# Console utf8 encoding conversion issue in VS2010

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, executenonquery

I'm trying to populate a table with Chinese characters using a C# console program. The characters are perfectly preserved in the C# string, but when I want to execute the query with:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It basically creates a conversion problem. I have been looking around on the net and found out that it has to do with the console encoding. So I tried changing it this but it doesn't work.

```
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Query before execution:

```
INSERT INTO Sentences (cat, q, a)
VALUES ('English -> Chinese; HSK level 1; limited 1;       part 1','He caught a cold. ;;;  tā gǎn mào le。','他感冒了。')
```

INSERT in table:

> English -> Chinese; HSK level 1; limited 1; part 1
>   He caught a cold. ;;;  ta gan mào le?
>   ?????

Direct query in phpmyadmin gives the desired result, so it's not a table encoding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding "Charset=utf8;" to my connection string. Got the answer from [THIS thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942277/mysql-c-sharp-text-encoding-problems) .

Answer (score 0):

Your query should have `N` before all string literals to make them unicode:

```
INSERT INTO Sentences (cat, q, a) VALUES (N'English -> Chinese; HSK level 1; limited 1; part 1',N'He caught a cold. ;;;  tā gǎn mào le。',N'他感冒了。')
```

Comment: Ok, I see that you fixed the problem anyway. You can accept your own answer.