# MySQL and VB.Net encoding

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good afternoon!
I'm building a Visual Basic 2013 application which inserts data to a MySQL database hosted on the Internet. Whenever I try to insert a new record with field values in Greek, they don't show up correctly in either phpMyAdmin or my application. I'm using utf8_unicode_ci collation for all my tables, and I use the same collation for all the table fields that require text entry.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using please

Comment: Which code exactly? The whole application is about 1000 lines of code long.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942277/mysql-c-sharp-text-encoding-problems)