# Unicode issue with C# and Php

Tags: c#, mysql, database, cyrillic

I haven't seen something similar here, but if there is sorry for the duplicate post. 
Here is my setup>> I use an "outdated" Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2010 on it. Please bear with me.

The C# 2010 Express has worked so far so good. Recently I've been working with a MySQL database which is hosted on a WAMP (or XAMP or easyPHP) server. I am connecting the C# application to the MySQL database manually. 
Now, I am having a problem with a software I'm developing for a Bulgarian project (so it has to support Cyrillic characters).

Here is the code>>

```
private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(); //connection
private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(); //adapter
connection.ConnectionString ="server=localhost;"+ "database=xxxxx;"+ "uid=root;"+ "password=;"; //connection string
try
{
    connection.Open(); //opening the connection
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand(); //creating a query
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM data"; //initial query for listing the table
    data.SelectCommand = command; //executing the query
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet(); //C# procedures, creating a dataset for gridview
    data.Fill(dataset, "sample_data"); //filling the dataset
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset; //setting up the dataset towards the gridview
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "sample_data"; //the data that are going to be sent...

}
```

And thus, I fill the dataGridView1 with the data from the database. And it is all good, the Cyrillic characters that have been filled up from before are looking good.

**Now for the problem>>**

If I want to send data into the database I write something like:

```
string comm1 = "INSERT INTO data (хххх, хххх) VALUES ('Abc', 'Абв')";
command.CommandText = comm1;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The first (latin) characters turn out to be fine, but the latter are not. In fact the database is filled up with question-mark signs (?).

**What I've tried so far:**

1. I'm using PhpMyAdmin for designing the database. If I try to send the desired Cyrillic characters via a PHP script, they end up written like this: Ð”Ñ€Ð°Ð³Ð°Ð½. If you read the DB from a browser they turn up to be fine (probably because of the various unicode supports they have got). But, **you can't search thru the DB normally**...
2. Changed the type of the column from **Varchar** to **Text**. It doesn't work.
3. I've changed the **collation** of the table all the way from **UTF-8**ci (case insensitive) to **Windows Cyrillic 1251 general**... and to **Bin**. It doesn't work.
4. I've tried changing the database engine. Went from **MylSAM**, to **InnoDB**... It doesn't work.
5. I've tried **manipulating the text** in the string
   `string commm2 = commm1.Replace("Дра", "\u0414 \u0440 \u0430");`. It doesn't work.
6. I've **converted the string**

   byte[] comm22 = Convert.FromBase64String(commm1);
   string commm3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(comm22);

. It doesn't work.

7. **Excluding the string** altogether... I've inputted the desired text directly in the function itself. It doesn't work.
8. I've tried **adding "@", "/""** in front of the string, in front of the characters. It doesn't work.

Comment: _In fact the database is filled up with question-mark signs (?)_ - Are you sure the problem is not displaying what is in the database?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942277/mysql-c-sharp-text-encoding-problems

Comment: @Wimmel 100% sure. Tried everything here

Comment: @JaggenSWE Interesting approach. This might light things up for me... Thanks, will try it and write till the end of the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem with Arabic strings in my php application ,i managed to solve it by executing the following query before sending or receiving data after making sure of tables and database collation setting set to utf8

```
        mysqli_set_charset('utf8',$this->connection);
        mysqli_query( $this->connection, 'SET NAMES "utf8" COLLATE "utf8_general_ci"' );
```

the problem is now solved but utf8 works  for arabic 
, no need to change anything but executing the SET NAMES query before the (insert/select) query

hope it helps

Comment: thank you for your answer... it generally drives me in the right direction. I'll give it a try in the following hours/days...

From the answers above, I have tried using

connection.ConnectionString ="server=localhost;"+ "database=xxxxx;"+ "uid=root;"+ "password=;" + "charset=utf8"; //connection string

so far so good... it seems that the charset must be defined early in the code - as you suggest

Comment: try executing this query right before insert and see how it works 
`' SET NAMES "utf8" COLLATE "utf8_general_ci" '`

Comment: Thank you for your support.
I've tried the code you gave me above, and it too seems to work. I've had to tweak it here and there, but generally it works. As I've mentioned earlier - it points me to the right direction.

I'll be testing it extensively in the following period...